# How can I make colores to be changed according to the value of scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this element:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ui-sref="sites.edit({siteId: site.Id})" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>
</a>
```

If this value:

```
$scope.IsValid = true;
```

I want the element to be in green color.

If this value:

```
$scope.IsValid = false;
```

I want the element to be in red color.

How can I make colres to be changed according to the value of `$scope.IsValid` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` assigning the right class (btn-green, btn-red):

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-class="{'btn-green': isValid, 'btn-red': !isValid}" ui-sref="sites.edit({siteId: site.Id})" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>
</a>
```

Check the classes you assign are present, this is only an example.